# Enterprise Standard for Linux server Penetration Testing

Tags: linux, penetration-test, vulnerability

Is there any enterprise or global standard like "OWASP" which can be followed while doing penetration testing on Linux servers?
I want to know if there are any most common/important vulnerabilities that must be covered while doing Linux server penetration testing?
OWASP has a top 10 vulnerability list that can be followed while doing Application vulnerability testing.

Comment: Automated scanners have all those "things to look for" built-in. Including patches and configuration issues.

Comment: actually I have enterprise licensed scanner (Nessus) by which I can get list of vulnerabilities of the targeted system. But I want to know the exact items for Penetration testing on a Linux server

Comment: I'm saying that the scanner has those items. Look at those lists as your guide.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually multiple methodologies that you can use as a guideline to do penetration testing. For example, you have [PTES](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page), which is used by some commercial pentesters.

However, the PTES is more than "OWASP Top 10 but for Linux", as it defines communication with the customer, threat modeling, etc. as well.